# Mongo aggregation throwing error: BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 68137138 bytes, past the 64MB limit

Tags: mongodb

I am running a mongo aggregation pipeline and I am getting an error. There is a collection `e` and it contains `tId`. I want to group all the data on `tId` and I want to loop over the updated data in batches.

> MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 68137138 bytes, past the 64MB limit.

The query I am running is

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {
      bId: new ObjectId(id),
      updatedAt: { $gte: startTime, $lte: endTime },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$tId",
      e: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "e._id": 1,
      "e.status": 1
    },
  },
];

const cursor2 = await db
  .collection("emails")
  .aggregate([...pipeline], { allowDiskUse: true, batchSize: 100 });
```

Please help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing aggregation pipeline the problem is `$group` stage.

If there are a lot of fields in your document avoid to `$push` entire document into group stage, just select two fields that you need after and change your aggregation like this:

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      bId: new ObjectId(id),
      updatedAt: { $gte: startTime, $lte: endTime },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$tId",
      e: {
       $push: {
         _id: "$$ROOT._id",
         status: "$$ROOT.status"
      },
    },
  }
]
```

Doing this last project step is unnecessary.

NOTE: this is a "workaround", if there are a lot of documents for same key "$tId", you must change your query approach (avoid group in this case) or change your datamodel